# Everytime I change my Microsoft Teams Tab's code the content of the tab does not change

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I am making a teams channel tab and everytime I update the code, the content loaded in the tab stays the same. I tried deleting the app and installing it again, rebuilding the manifest, nothing works.

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
  "version": "{{VERSION}}",
  "packageName": "{{PACKAGE_NAME}}",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Vizibit",
    "websiteUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}",
    "privacyUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Teams Add In",
    "full": "Teams Add In"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/teamsAddInTab/config.html?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&theme={theme}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "sharePointPreviewImage": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/assets/teamsAddInTab-preview.png",
      "supportedSharePointHosts": [
        "sharePointFullPage",
        "sharePointWebPart"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": false,
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "{{TAB_APP_ID}}",
    "resource": "{{TAB_APP_URI}}"
  }
}
```

Here is the code that gets rendered:

```
   return (
        // <Provider theme={theme}>
        //     <Flex fill={true} column styles={{
        //         padding: ".8rem 0 .8rem .5rem"
        //     }}>
        //         <Flex.Item>
        //             <Header content="This is your tab" />
        //         </Flex.Item>
        //         <Flex.Item>
        //             <div>
        //                 <div>
        //                     <Text content={`Hello ${name}`} />
        //                 </div>
        //                 {error && <div><Text content={`An SSO error occurred ${error}`} /></div>}

        //                 <div>
        //                     <Button onClick={() => alert("It worked!")}>A sample button</Button>
        //                 </div>
        //             </div>
        //         </Flex.Item>
        //         <Flex.Item styles={{
        //             padding: ".8rem 0 .8rem .5rem"
        //         }}>
        //             <Text size="smaller" content="(C) Copyright Vizibit" />
        //         </Flex.Item>
        //     </Flex>
        // </Provider>

        <div>asd</div>
    );
```

It is all commented out, it should only show 'asd' on screen, but it shows the commented part.

Here's what it shows all the time:

[image: teams tab]

Comment: It would be because of cache. Signout of the teams and sign in back to get cache refreshed or Clear Teams cache.

Comment: I get it that it is because of cache, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I don't believe that the browser component in the Teams client caches any content, I think this would likely be cached on the server end (or something in between)? I've seen this happen with ASP.Net quite often. A little frustrating but restarting the web server fixes it in the cases that I've seen.